# axis jar conflict in bea weblogic9

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, apache-axis, weblogic9.x

I created simple web service client called GroupServiceReadinessInterface which extends org.apache.axis.client.Service(located in axis-1.2.1-patched.jar).When i called the client from test class works fine but after deploy my application into bea weblogic 9 the web service return status 500 and there is no response from the web service. I think this is aconflict between my application Libs and weblogic libraries any helps please.

public class GroupServiceReadinessInterface_ServiceLocator extends
        org.apache.axis.client.Service implements
        de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterface_Service {

```
public GroupServiceReadinessInterface_ServiceLocator() {
}

public GroupServiceReadinessInterface_ServiceLocator(
        org.apache.axis.EngineConfiguration config) {
    super(config);
}

public GroupServiceReadinessInterface_ServiceLocator(
        java.lang.String wsdlLoc, javax.xml.namespace.QName sName)
        throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    super(wsdlLoc, sName);
}

// Use to get a proxy class for GroupServiceReadinessPort
private java.lang.String GroupServiceReadinessPort_address = "http://vf_nb_group_service_readiness_service/GroupServiceReadinessServiceMock/GroupServiceReadinessInterface/GroupServiceReadinessPort";

public java.lang.String getGroupServiceReadinessPortAddress() {
    return GroupServiceReadinessPort_address;
}

// The WSDD service name defaults to the port name.
private java.lang.String GroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName = "GroupServiceReadinessPort";

public java.lang.String getGroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName() {
    return GroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName;
}

public void setGroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName(
        java.lang.String name) {
    GroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName = name;
}

public de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterface_PortType getGroupServiceReadinessPort()
        throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    java.net.URL endpoint;
    try {
        endpoint = new java.net.URL(GroupServiceReadinessPort_address);
    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException(e);
    }
    return getGroupServiceReadinessPort(endpoint);
}

public de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterface_PortType getGroupServiceReadinessPort(
        java.net.URL portAddress) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    try {
        de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterfaceBindingStub _stub = new de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterfaceBindingStub(
                portAddress, this);
        _stub.setPortName(getGroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName());
        return _stub;
    } catch (org.apache.axis.AxisFault e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public void setGroupServiceReadinessPortEndpointAddress(
        java.lang.String address) {
    GroupServiceReadinessPort_address = address;
}

/**
 * For the given interface, get the stub implementation. If this service has
 * no port for the given interface, then ServiceException is thrown.
 */
public java.rmi.Remote getPort(Class serviceEndpointInterface)
        throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    try {
        if (de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterface_PortType.class
                .isAssignableFrom(serviceEndpointInterface)) {
            de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterfaceBindingStub _stub = new de.vodafone.ws.serviceready.GroupServiceReadinessInterfaceBindingStub(
                    new java.net.URL(GroupServiceReadinessPort_address),
                    this);
            _stub.setPortName(getGroupServiceReadinessPortWSDDServiceName());
            return _stub;
        }
    } catch (java.lang.Throwable t) {
        throw new javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException(t);
    }
    throw new javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException(
            "There is no stub implementation for the interface:  "
                    + (serviceEndpointInterface == null ? "null"
                            : serviceEndpointInterface.getName()));
}

/**
 * For the given interface, get the stub implementation. If this service has
 * no port for the given interface, then ServiceException is thrown.
 */
public java.rmi.Remote getPort(javax.xml.namespace.QName portName,
        Class serviceEndpointInterface)
        throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    if (portName == null) {
        return getPort(serviceEndpointInterface);
    }
    java.lang.String inputPortName = portName.getLocalPart();
    if ("GroupServiceReadinessPort".equals(inputPortName)) {
        return getGroupServiceReadinessPort();
    } else {
        java.rmi.Remote _stub = getPort(serviceEndpointInterface);
        ((org.apache.axis.client.Stub) _stub).setPortName(portName);
        return _stub;
    }
}

public javax.xml.namespace.QName getServiceName() {
    return new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
            "http://www.vodafone.com/vf/lig/groupServiceReadiness/service/v1",
            "GroupServiceReadinessInterfaceMock");
}

private java.util.HashSet ports = null;

public java.util.Iterator getPorts() {
    if (ports == null) {
        ports = new java.util.HashSet();
        ports.add(new javax.xml.namespace.QName(
                "http://www.vodafone.com/vf/lig/groupServiceReadinessMock/service/v1",
                "GroupServiceReadinessPort"));
    }
    return ports.iterator();
}

/**
 * Set the endpoint address for the specified port name.
 */
public void setEndpointAddress(java.lang.String portName,
        java.lang.String address) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {

    if ("GroupServiceReadinessPort".equals(portName)) {
        setGroupServiceReadinessPortEndpointAddress(address);
    } else { // Unknown Port Name
        throw new javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException(
                " Cannot set Endpoint Address for Unknown Port" + portName);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the endpoint address for the specified port name.
 */
public void setEndpointAddress(javax.xml.namespace.QName portName,
        java.lang.String address) throws javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException {
    setEndpointAddress(portName.getLocalPart(), address);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/app_server.html) before .Please go through once about integration of axis with WL9